# Expo Snack Error: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Expo Snack link: https://snack.expo.dev/@ronbutan/mre-flowtime

I imported the code from GitHub and updated all the dependencies such that it now fits Expo Snack requirements but now I get an error "undefined is not a function" and I don't know how to fix it as I don't know what is even undefined. My app which I imported from GitHub works fine but now when I import it into Expo Snack it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm getting an unmatched route error since we are only allowed app.js in snack I believe